# Can't pickle _thread.RLock objects using redis queue

Tags: python, redis

```
import tweepy
import dataset
from textblob import TextBlob
from sqlalchemy.exc import ProgrammingError
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
from redis import Redis
from rq import Queue
q = Queue(connection = Redis())
class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

        def on_status(self, status):
            if status.retweeted:
                return

            text = status.text
            blob = TextBlob(text)
            sent = blob.sentiment
            dictToInsert = dict(
                    text = text,
                    created = status.created_at,
                    id_str = status.id_str,
                    retweet_count = status.retweet_count,
                    polarity = sent.polarity,
                    subjectivity = sent.subjectivity,
                )

            table = db["KeyWordTest"]
            try:
                **result = q.enqueue(table.insert, dictToInsert)**
            except ProgrammingError as err:
                print(err)
```

I am trying to stream tweets and insert them into MySQL with Redis Queue to handle cases when my program can't process fast enough.

I met this error when using enqueue. I think the reason is that I can only put a function rather than table.function. But I don't know how can I rewrite this.

Comment: You trying to pass open connection to separate process, which is imposible

Comment: Then what can I do instead to achieve the same result?

Comment: In theory - you could make some simple API which will accept dictionary somehow ( like POST request or send via sockets or whatever ) and put in into database using single connection. Secondary, create function that will feed your dictionary to your API and pass that function to redis queue.